# rails 3.1, how can I define a form that posts to a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to know how can I create a form that submits to a helper method ?

I don't need to write a route for some action in a controller, because this form will gather info using radio & check boxes, and then, I will create a model in the helper and do redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't post to helper method execpt if helper method is also controller action

```
class SampleController << ApplicationController
   helper_method :helper_and_action

   def helper_and_action
     # do some stuff

     # you need to skip render view if you use this method as helper
   end

end
```

register it in route.rb

```
 post "sample/helper_and_action", :controller=> :sample, :action=> :helper_and_action
```

then make view something like below

```
<%= form_tag {:controller => :sample, :action=> :helper_and_action } do |f| %>
 ... its up to you what will go here
<% end %>
```